# C# Base Class Method reuse with different client

Tags: c#

I have a base class and 3 client inherit from base and all of them will use a same method with tiny logic change.

Should I implement this method in 3 client class or Can I use if else in base class?

```
public class BaseClass
{
    protected string className;
    public BaseClass()
    {
        className = "Base";
    }
    private void ReuseMethod()
    {
         commonLogic1();
         if (className.Equal("A") commonLogic2();
         commonLogic3();
         if (className.Equal("B") commonLogic4();
         commonLogic5();
         if (className.Equal("C") commonLogic6();
    }
}
public class ClassA : BaseClass
{
    public ClassA() : Base()
    {
        className = "A";
    }
}
public class ClassB : BaseClass
{
    public ClassB() : Base()
    {
        className = "B";
    }
}
public class ClassC : BaseClass
{
    public ClassC() : Base()
    {
        className = "C";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by others there is a big amount of possibilities here depending on your real world use case.

As the commonLogicX() seems to be only relevant for one specific class you could add empty virtual methods for special steps that could be implemented by inheriting classes:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass()
    {
        className = "Base";
    }
    private void ReuseMethod()
    {
         commonLogic1();
         commonLogic2();
         commonLogic3();
         commonLogic4();
         commonLogic5();
         commonLogic6();
    }

    protected virtual void commonLogic2() { }
    protected virtual void commonLogic4() { }
    protected virtual void commonLogic6() { }
}
public class ClassA : BaseClass
{
    public ClassA() : Base()
    {
        protected override void commonLogic2(){
           // DoSomethingSpecial
        }
    }
}
```

This will work if there is a limited amount of points where you can interfere with the algorithm.

Another - maybe more flexible option - would be use some kind of pipeline you can manipulate.

```
public class StepExecutor() {
   public StepExecutor(StepType type, Action action) {
       this.Type = type;
       this.Action = action;
   }
   StepType Type {get;}
   Action Action {get;}
}
public enum StepType {
    Step1,
    Step2,
    Step3,
    Step4,
    Step5,
    Step6
}
public class BaseClass
{
    protected List<StepExecutor> Steps = new List<StepExecutor>();
    public BaseClass()
    {
        className = "Base";
        // Maybe replace this with a StepFactory?
        BuildDefaultSteps();
    }

    protected virtual void BuildDefaultSteps() {
     Steps.Add(new StepExecutor(StepType.Step1,() => commonLogic1()));
     Steps.Add(new StepExecutor(StepType.Step3,() => commonLogic3()));
     Steps.Add(new StepExecutor(StepType.Step5,() => commonLogic5()));
   }
    private void ReuseMethod()
    {
         foreach(var step in Steps) {
             step.Action.Execute();
         }
    }
}
public class ClassA : BaseClass
{
    public ClassA() : Base()
    {
        var index = Steps.IndexOf(c => c.Type == StepType.Step1);
        Steps.Insert(index+1,new StepExecutor(StepType.Step2, () => commonLogic2()));
    }
}
```

Using a Builder-Pattern might also be an option.

Answer (score 2):

I will just add to the answers mentioned by explaining why you should not make such conditional statements in the base class. When you make it this way you make coupling and dependency between the derived classes by making some of their logic in one class, since when you try to update the method's logic for one of the derived classes the other ones might be affected since they are all in one place and may depend on the same private members and so a new build will be required for all of them and the testing should cover all the dependent logic. The risk of this become more clear over time when you update\ add a new logic to this method or make the same conditional statements for other methods in the base class.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am agree your point, however, since commonLogic1 to 5 execute with order, If use virtual or abstract and implement in client class, the commonLogic1 and 3 will duplicate in each client. is this make sense?

Comment: @JoshTseng I'm not sure what is the logic you are structuring for, but generally in these cases you can make other base classes for each situation, or you can make a separate class to cover each separate behavior (a common logic). Either way I highly recommend you to read about Composition over Inheritance : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Answer (score 0):

Depends where `ReuseMethod` gets called from and the context

If its called from the client classes, then just do it in the client classes

If it's called from the base class, then the client classes should implement a virtual or abstract method.

There is also the possibility the common logic should be another class and then you should inject it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It's only called from base class and the commonLogic1, 2, 3,4,5 execute has order. if client implement the virtual or abstract method, the commonLogic1 method will duplicate in each client, is this make sense?